# Findall with multiple variables in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

I would like to get a list of solutions from a rule I made in Prolog.

However the findall predicate appears to only work with one variable.

Can anyone suggest how to get around this apparent limitation?

My rule

```
beat(P,M,E)
```

What I want

```
L = [[P,M],[P,M],................]
```

What I get now

```
L = [P,P,P,P,.........]
```

or

```
L = [M,M,M,M,M.............]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`findall` can work with a surprisingly flexible amount of variations. I think you want something like this:

```
findall([P,M], beat(P,M,E), L).
```

Comment: @ReiiYuki Please, mark the answer as accepted if this is the solution you need, so other users can find this answer helpful too.

Comment: Can you reference to the docs of this feature.

Comment: @eguneys https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions (for swi-prolog), but this is an ISO standard for all prologs, so you can find this in any of the docs for g-prolog, sicstus, etc.

Comment: That doesn't mention the usage you provided as solution, like using a list as the first parameter.

Comment: @eguneys You can't find that information in a doc on a predicate. That knowledge comes from solid understanding of what terms, compound, terms, atoms, and unification is in prolog, and ... how a findall/N template relates to that fundamental understanding.

Comment: @eguneys The template parameter in findall/3 can literally unify with any type of term you can imagine. There is no limit, it is strictly a function of unification and backtracking over predicates. It's so flexible you can even do something like this, which seems ostensibly nonsensical for most use-cases: findall(1, beat(P,M,E), L). In that case for every successful unification, or proof of beat(P,M,E), you add another element `1` to a list L, and the aggregated results are unified with the variable `L`. There really are no restrictions on findall templates beyond violations of Prolog itself.

Comment: @eguneys In other words, this is more a "feature" of the language itself rather than findall/3.